# How to Save Data & Open Print Window in one click?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

```
<body>
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtName" placeholder="Enter Your Name Please" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtAdd" placeholder="Enter Your Address Please" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Click to Save Me...." /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I Click Submit Button Data are Saved in Database.

But I want When i submit data data will save and print window should be open

Comment: this would be done using javascript. Presumably you want to open the print window only if the save was successful? (No validation errors, no network/server problems). In which case use your server-side language to inject some script back into the page to open the print window when the page refreshes after a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this one**

For saving data and open print window in one click you have to use AJAX and on success of AJAX you can open print window. For this change your submit button to simple button and call ajax on button click.

OR

After submitting form you can add script tag instead of header function.

```
<script>
  window.open(URL)
</script>
```